# How to get ROS_MASTER_URI so that other devices can also connect to it?

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri

Currently, when I run `roscore`, I can `ROS_MASTER_URI` in terms of localhost.
I want to get `ROS_MASTER_URI` s.t. other devices can also connect to the ROS Network. for ex:

`ROS_MASTER_URI = 172.XX.XXX.XX:11311`

I have already tried using

`setx ROS_MASTER_URI http://172.XX.XXX.XX:11311`

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Please check ROS network setup from [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup).

Comment: Did you use `setx ROS_MASTER_URI http://172.XX.XXX.XX:11311` or did you use `set ROS_MASTER_URI http://172.XX.XXX.XX:11311` ?
 
 Try `set ROS_MASTER_URI=http://172.XX.XXX.XX:11311`

Answer (score 0):

On Linux:

set Env variable

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=IP_ADDRESS
```

get Env variable

```
echo ROS_MASTER_URI
```

On Windows:
set Env variable from PowerShell

```
$env:ROS_MASTER_URI = 'IP_ADDRESS'
```

get Env variable

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Env:
```